# Getting mail from GMail into Java application using IMAP

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

I want to access messages in Gmail from a Java application using [JavaMail](http://www.ing.iac.es/~docs/external/java/javamail/javadocs/index.html) and [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol). Why am I getting a *[SocketTimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)* ?

Here is my code:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", "imap.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", "5000");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.timeout", "5000");

try {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new MyAuthenticator());
    URLName urlName = new URLName("imap://MYUSERNAME@gmail.com:MYPASSWORD@imap.gmail.com");
    Store store = session.getStore(urlName);
    if (!store.isConnected()) {
        store.connect();
    }
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(2);
}
```

I have set the timeout values so that it wouldn't take "forever" to timeout. Also, *MyAuthenticator* also has the username and password, which seems redundant with the URL. Is there another way to specify the protocol? (I didn't see it in the JavaDoc for [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol).)

Comment: If you want access GMail threads using JavaMail you might be interested in http://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/

Comment: Do any of these IMAP-based solutions work anymore *without* the need to "Allow less secure apps"?

Comment: Related:  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/what-are-the-dangers-of-allowing-less-secure-apps-to-access-my-google-account

Answer (score 71):

Using imaps was a great suggestion. Neither of the answers provided just worked for me, so I googled some more and found something that worked. Here's how my code looks now.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
try {
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
  Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
  store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>@gmail.com", "<password>");
  ...
} catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(1);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(2);
}
```

This is nice because it takes the redundant Authenticator out of the picture. I'm glad this worked because the SSLNOTES.txt make my head spin.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the following properties for imaps:

```
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.connectiontimeout", "5000");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.timeout", "5000");
```

Notices it's "imaps", not "imap", since the protocol you're using is imaps (IMAP + SSL)

Answer (score 6):

In JavaMail, you can use `imaps` as the URL scheme to use IMAP over SSL. (See `SSLNOTES.txt` in your JavaMail distribution for more details.) For example, `imaps://username%40gmail.com@imap.gmail.com/INBOX`.

Similarly, use `smtps` to send emails via Gmail. e.g., `smtps://username%40gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com/`. Again, read `SSLNOTES.txt` for more details. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You have to connect to GMail using SSL only. Setting the following properties will force that for you.

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Comment: I don't recommend this approach in general, because it overrides _all_ imap connections to be imaps. Sometimes choice is a good thing, especially if the program is to be used for connecting to just Gmail.

However, if you think plain IMAP is outright wrong, then this approach is acceptable. :-)

Comment: ...used for connecting to _more than_ just Gmail, I meant. :-P

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for my team and I, given a classic account nickname@gmail.com and a business account employee@business.com :

```
            final Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");

            imapSession = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
            imapSession.setDebug(false);
            imapStore = imapSession.getStore("imap");

            imapStore.connect("imap.gmail.com", USERNAME, "password");
```

with USERNAME = "nickname" in the classic case, and USERNAME = "employee@business.com" in the business account case.

In the classic case, don't forget to lower the account security here : https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

In both cases check in GMail *Settings => Forwarding POP / IMAP* if IMAP is enabled for the account.

Hope it helps!

To go further :

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail
- https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754

Comment: What do you mean by "old JavaMail dependency"?  I don't think this has anything to do with the JavaMail version, it's that you're connecting with IMAPS instead of OAUTH2.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like more sample code on using JavaMail with Gmail (e.g. converting Gmail labels to IMAP folder names, or using IMAP IDLE), do check out my program [GmailAssistant](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/) on [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Check http://g4j.sourceforge.net/. There is a minimal gmail client built using this API.

Answer (score 1):

I used following properties to get the store and It works well.

`"mail.imaps.host" : "imap.gmail.com" 

"mail.store.protocol" : "imaps" 

"mail.imaps.port" : "993"`

Answer (score 0):

```
URLName server = new URLName("imaps://<gmail-user-name>:<gmail-pass>@imap.gmail.com/INBOX");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have JSSE installed to use SSL with Java