# Access gmail from Java

Tags: java, gmail

I need a library that allows me to do email operations(e.g Sent/Receive mail) in Gmail using Java.

Comment: Via IMAP? Via POP3/SMTP? Provide more information, otherwise it's a "Ask Google" question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you seen [g4j - GMail API for Java](http://g4j.sourceforge.net/)?

> GMailer API for Java (g4j) is set of
>   API that allows Java programmer to
>   communicate to GMail. With G4J
>   programmers can made Java based
>   application that based on huge storage
>   of GMail.

Comment: What about using pop3? And does g4j stay current when/if gmail updates/changes their html rendererd client?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Javamail for that. The thing to remember is that GMail uses SMTPS not SMTP.

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

import java.util.Properties;


public class SimpleSSLMail {

    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private static final int SMTP_HOST_PORT = 465;
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "myaccount@gmail.com";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "mypwd";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
       new SimpleSSLMail().test();
    }

    public void test() throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
        props.put("mail.smtps.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
        // props.put("mail.smtps.quitwait", "false");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setSubject("Testing SMTP-SSL");
        message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");

        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             new InternetAddress("elvis@presley.org"));

        transport.connect
          (SMTP_HOST_NAME, SMTP_HOST_PORT, SMTP_AUTH_USER, SMTP_AUTH_PWD);

        transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Variations of this question have been addressed in several earlier posts:

- [Getting mail from GMail into Java application using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176/getting-mail-from-gmail-into-java-application-using-imap)
- [How do you send email from a Java app using Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail)

The general approach is to use IMAP/SMTP via [JavaMail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/). The [FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html) even has a special entry for [working with Gmail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html#gmail).

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [GMail API for Java](http://g4j.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

First, configure your Gmail account to accept POP3 access.
Then, simply access your mail account using Javamail !