# Monitoring an email inbox using Java

Tags: java, email, automation, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access gmail from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483048/access-gmail-from-java)

I would like to make a small java app on my windows machine to monitor my (or any other) gmail inbox. I would like it so the app is notified when the email comes in and it does not have to poll the inbox every x seconds/minutes. Is there a publicly available library for this? (I will also need to inspect the content of the email: sender, timestamps, subject, body, attachments, etc...)

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483048/access-gmail-from-java)

Answer (score 2):

- As of the API to handle mail account, see other answer(s). I recommend JavaMail because of its flexibility
- As of polling - i do not know any library that does the polling for you. But with a little helper class based on java.util.concurrent scheduled exeutor this should be a no brainer.