# Can someone explain the line URLName in javamail?

Tags: jakarta-mail

can someone explain the line:

> URLName server = new URLName("protocol://username@host/foldername");

If i use Gmail.
what is

```
> protocol = is it smtp.gmail.com?? 
> username@host = email@gmail.com ??
> foldername = inbox from my gmail??
```

Answer (score 0):

The protocol depends on the functionality you wish to implement:

- SMTP - sending mails
- POP - getting mails
- IMAP - both

Please also have a look at the [Javamail FAQ related to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#gmail%20FAQ) or this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483048/access-gmail-from-java)

Comment: i want to get attachment file from my email.

Comment: i try this URLName server = new URLName("pop://mail.google.com/myemail@mypassword/pop/") and i have error message like : Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for pop
 at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:464)
 at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:539)
 at javax.mail.Session.getFolder(Session.java:611)
 at EmailWrite.main(EmailWrite.java:12)

Comment: That's because the protocol is not named "pop", it's named "pop3".  Did you read the JavaMail FAQ referred to above?  Note also that you never **need** to use URLName, and you can generally do what you need to much more simply without it.  Again, see the FAQ.