# How can i use my gmail as SMTP and use it in java code to send email.?

Tags: java, email

My application is need to send email to the selected persons.
my application is totally java based.
and i even i dont know how to use my gmail account as SMTP mail.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/483218/49251

Comment: http://tutorial4java.blogspot.in/2012/07/java-mail-api-tutorial.html Check This Blog too... Provides good information...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you send email from a Java app using Gmail?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663/how-do-you-send-email-from-a-java-app-using-gmail)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample, change `from`, `pass` and `to` based on your requirement

```
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
String from = "username";
String pass = "password";
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); // added this line
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

String[] to = {"to@gmail.com"}; // added this line

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

// To get the array of addresses
for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { // changed from a while loop
    toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
}
System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { // changed from a while loop
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
}
message.setSubject("sending in a group");
message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, from, pass);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply...
Now can you please tell about gmail smtp.?

Comment: This is for GMAIL SMTP only. Please refer the smtp host name and port. String host = "smtp.gmail.com". Its pointing to Gmail only. Just add your user name in _from_ and password in _pass_. The code will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/) is all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in windows you can use Fake Sendmail with wamp server its works great her is a tutorial to how install it and configure it :

http://glob.com.au/sendmail/