# How to avoid Selenium integration tests being considered suspicious logins

Tags: selenium, google-oauth

We are doing tests for our Google OpenAuth integration using Selenium on multiple different platforms/browsers using a couple of different cloud providers. For all tests, we are using the same Google account, which was created for this purpose. We are continuously running into the issue that these logins (from the different providers and their devices around the world) are being considered suspicious logins and therefore rejected [1]. How is it possible to avoid this problem of these integration tests being considered suspicious logins? Is it possible to disable this detection? Do Google have test-users that one can use? Do we need to proxy the requests, so they always come from the same address? Please beware, that since we are using Selenium as a service, we have no control of the clients and their location.

Any ideas?

[1] https://security.google.com/settings/u/2/security/activity

Comment: In test, you should set up your own test equipment that is under your (organization's) control. You should avoid continuously hitting somebody else's equipment, and you should definitely not expect somebody else to accommodate your test scenarios. Of course, if you are _paying_ for this third-party equipment, then everything changes, and you should contact their customer support.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas, and I very much agree that one should no use others "equipment" for testing. We use Google (among many other OAuth providers) for the authentication service that they provide and for that service they have chosen to charge 0$ (as a service to us and their own users). In order to test that our integration with them works I have found no other way than actually loading their login page - a mock in an integration test does not make sense in my world. It would also be my guess, that Google share interest in that it actually works for anyone trying to use their service.

Comment: I would really like to know Google's view on how we could optimize our integration tests again them, but unfortunately I have not been able to find any documentation on their website (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). And they are referencing themselves to SO for questions (https://developers.google.com/accounts/forum). Finally, I think that we have different definitions of continuously, since we are currently hitting Google with 5 login requests pr day

Comment: 1/2 of me wants to kill this question since there really is no answer, but the other half is so glad you asked it!  This is a terrible situation that were in, if we run the tests we get banned, if we do not test, things fail for users.  Good Question, if you ever find a solution the world would benefit from it.  (I use selenium to test IDP, and I have the same issue.)

Comment: Hitting this problem as well. Anyone find an alternative to this?

Comment: Same problem here, still not fully solved, either google makes a simple option in settings to disable verification after email/password or we have to cooperate to list all possible triggers that google uses to detect automation.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can recommend is to utilize Google's API's instead of going through their webapp.  They most likely have added security for their web apps.

For example, if you are trying to retrieve mail, then [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483048/access-gmail-from-java).

Comment: My purpose is not to fetch emails, but rather test a user that uses Google OpenAuth for login: a user lands on our front page page, selects Google for login, then being sent to Google for authentication and comes back with the oauth token which is used for further validation. I have been able to find any documentation at Google on how to do integration test of this other than loading their login page. Any suggestion on how to test this in another way?