# javax.mail.search alternative for getting newest message

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta, dovecot

Aside from [javax.mail.search.SentDateTerm](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/mail/search/SentDateTerm.html), what's a good way to get the newest message in a particular [Movemail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movemail) folder?

It looks like doveadm is [the way to go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5302192/262852), although I cannot find a Java driver.  However, I'd rather stay within postfix and am not terribly keen on using POP3 (or IMAP), although the [integrated Ubuntu stack](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/dovecot-postfix) has alleviated configuration hassles.  Any alternatives to javax.mail.search?

The problem I see with javax.mail.search.SentDateTerm is that it requires iterating the folder, which, for large folders, could be problematic.  In this case I only want the "newest" message, by sent date.

I'm using Thunderbird to read POP3, but was using a [mailutils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_%28Unix%29) type folder and want to pop the top message, as if were a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29).  Really, just the same thing you seen Thunderbird where the latest message is at the top.

I suppose that it might be feasible to resort to using the file system to sort mail:

```
root@dur:~# 
root@dur:~# head /var/mail/root 
From root@dur.bounceme.net  Sun Aug 26 00:41:11 2012
Return-Path: <root@dur.bounceme.net>
X-Original-To: root@dur
Delivered-To: root@dur
Received: by dur.bounceme.net (Postfix, from userid 0)
    id AB90A1827DF; Sun, 26 Aug 2012 00:41:11 -0700 (PDT)
To: <thufir@dur>
Cc: <root@dur>
Subject: ping 12:40
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.2)
root@dur:~#
```

Something in Java along those lines to grab the top message?  However, **that seems fragile** and just generally a bad idea, to use the filesystem directly when there may be better options.  Perhaps there's some mailutils or postfix hook which Java can take advantage of?  An existing API?

**One problem with the example command `head /var/mail/root` is that it grabs the top message, whereas I'm after the top message in a particular folder.**

I've switched to dovecot for POP3, but am looking for a good way to interact with the messages which have been popped.  This is [probably the best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127081/262852), but how do you get the top or latest message **without** iterating the entire folder?

See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129820/dovecot-doveadm-java-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the newest message by **sent** date, you have to look at all the messages.  If you want the newest message by **received** date, it's easier - that's the last message in the Inbox.

Comment: just get the size of the inbox, and then the last message -1?

Comment: That's the most recently **received** message, not the most recently **sent** message.  Remember, email is store and forward - there can be arbitrary delays anywhere along the path.

Comment: @BillShannon can you please look at this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415845/why-does-bodypart-ismimetypetext-plain-gives-error-unable-to-load-bodystr