# Why does 'bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")' give the error 'Unable to load bodystructure'?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am creating an application in Java to read mails from my GoDaddy webmail through Java. I have used javax.mail for this.
When I debug the program, it gives an error at the line: `bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")`

Unexpectedly, it processes the first mail in the right way but gives the error for the second mail.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Unable to load BODYSTRUCTURE
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.loadBODYSTRUCTURE(IMAPMessage.java:1306)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage.getContentType(IMAPMessage.java:465)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.isMimeType(MimeBodyPart.java:1050)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.isMimeType(MimeMessage.java:986)
    at asanaLambdaIntegrationDebugMode.getNameMailIdFromMessage(asanaLambdaIntegrationDebugMode.java:1318)
    at asanaLambdaIntegrationDebugMode.main(asanaLambdaIntegrationDebugMode.java:978)
```

Any suggestions on this please?

Comment: This is usually due to a bug in the server.  What version of JavaMail are you using and what does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: The stack trace is not the same as the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  The JavaMail FAQ describes a [workaround for these IMAP server bugs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#imapserverbug).

Comment: Edit your original post and add it there.  Replace any sensitive data with “XXX”.

Answer (score 8):

Give a try to the workaround described here:
https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#imapserverbug

Hope this helps.