# How to read Google/Yahoo mail inbox using java?

Tags: java, email

I want to make a program which can read email (subject, sender, body message) in Yahoo & Google mail.

I originally thought to use POP3 but I read on the internet POP3 can't read the mail box.

Does anyone know of / can suggest a Java library for this problem?

Comment: IMAP is the protocol you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Peek here:

[Getting mail from GMail into Java application using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176/getting-mail-from-gmail-into-java-application-using-imap)

Answer (score 1):

Java itself provides [Java Mail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/index.jsp)s to enable mail functionalities. You can also find third party APIs at [here.](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html)

Comment: Isn't Java Mail is read POP3, and POP3 can't read mail inbox?

Answer (score 0):

GMail provides an ATOM feed of unread mail that uses HTTP Basic authentication:

http://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom

Comment: ATOM feed provides very limited function. Can only get the briefing of messages. If requirement is simple, can use feed/atom. But using IMAP via OAUTH (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview) can provide much more features.