# Accessing gmail via imap using Javamail (behind a proxy)

Tags: java, proxy, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I am using code from on the earlier threads(have pasted the code below as well):

[Getting mail from GMail into Java application using IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176/getting-mail-from-gmail-into-java-application-using-imap)

How do I make this code work if I am behind a proxy?

The connection is getting timed out, I have tried to search for a solution but to no avail.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, password);
            System.out.println(store);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();
            for(Message message:messages) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }

}
```

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behind the proxy doesn't stop you to connect to IMAP

There could be 2 reasons

1. The IMAP port is block by your network administrator
2. your IP is blocked/banned by Google

Thanks

Comment: I tried pinging imap.google.com: "Ping request could not find host imap.google.com. Please check the name and try again."  . How do I know if my ip is banned? Thanks, Chris.

Comment: confirmed network issue. contact your ISP or network administrator.

Comment: @mtariq how did you find that it's network issue and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

[Check out the Java Mail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#proxy):

> **Q:** How do I configure JavaMail to work
>   through my proxy server?
>
> **A:** JavaMail
>   does not currently support accessing
>   mail servers through a web proxy
>   server. One of the major reasons for
>   using a proxy server is to allow HTTP
>   requests from within a corporate
>   network to pass through a corporate
>   firewall. The firewall will typically
>   block most access to the Internet, but
>   will allow requests from the proxy
>   server to pass through. In addition, a
>   mail server inside the corporate
>   network will perform a similar
>   function for email, accepting messages
>   via SMTP and forwarding them to their
>   ultimate destination on the Internet,
>   and accepting incoming messages and
>   sending them to the appropriate
>   internal mail server.
>
> If your proxy server supports the
>   SOCKS V4 or V5 protocol
>   (http://www.socks.nec.com/aboutsocks.html,
>   RFC1928) and allows anonymous
>   connections, you can tell the Java
>   runtime to direct all TCP socket
>   connections to the SOCKS server. See
>   the Networking Properties guide for
>   the latest documentation of the
>   socksProxyHost and socksProxyPort
>   properties. These are system-level
>   properties, not JavaMail session
>   properties. They can be set from the
>   command line when the application is
>   invoked, for example: java
>   -DsocksProxyHost=myproxy .... This facility can be used to direct the
>   SMTP, IMAP, and POP3 communication
>   from JavaMail to the SOCKS proxy
>   server. Note that setting these
>   properties directs all TCP sockets to
>   the SOCKS proxy, which may have
>   negative impact on other aspects of
>   your application.
>
> Without such a SOCKS server, if you
>   want to use JavaMail to directly
>   access mail servers outside the
>   firewall, the firewall will need to be
>   configured to allow such access.
>   JavaMail does not support access
>   through a HTTP proxy web server.