# How do I bridge activity on a Google Apps email address to a Java program on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, email

I need a Java program running on Windows to react to incoming email on a specific Google Apps email address.

I am not against using any sort of middleman program or language to accomplish this as easily and reliably as possible.

What are my best options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate with Google directly.

http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

...or you can fetch email from the Gmail account using [IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176/getting-mail-from-gmail-into-java-application-using-imap) or [POP3](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Email/JavaMailPOP3Client.htm).