# Code to receive an email from gmail account in myandriod application

Tags: android, gmail

My android application need to communicate with the gmail server to receive emails from other gmail accounts so that i can show the e-mails in my android application..
Can anybody suggest me a API or Docs or tutorial to accomplish this....
Thanks in advance.....

Regards,
HONY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably want to interface with a [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imap) or a [POP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) mail server. Just lookup on Google. I'm sure that there are already libraries for Java (maybe also for Android) avaiable.

This SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176/getting-mail-from-gmail-into-java-application-using-imap) discuesses how to connect to a Gmail server in a desktop java application, but I think you can port it also to android.