# how can get https content of gmail whitout 403 exception?

Tags: java

how can get https content of gmail whitout 403 exception?

i want get content of an https url of google but i cannot read the response in my browser i have response but in my app i have 403 exception
 this code have 403 exception but if open the url in browser i can see the response i want get this response and print in console

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        String text = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?Content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded&accountType=GOOGLE&Email=EMAIL&Passwd=aaaaaa";
        URLConnection connection = new URL(text).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: If you want to get at mails, why not [use IMAP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview) and avoid all of that screen scraping you're about to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a user and a password. The reason why you can access your mail directly with the brower is because gmail uses cookies to allow you to bypass log in screen.

**EDIT**

It is much better to use POP or IMAP API to programtically access your mailbox.
Here is [another question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61176/getting-mail-from-gmail-into-java-application-using-imap) and a [library](http://code.google.com/p/java-gmail-imap/) that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can read mail using this tutorial:

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/62143-how-to-read-your-emails-using-java/